# How can I change the size of this flutter Material Button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I would like to change the size of the button, by reducing the vertical size so it is a bit squished.
The current code that I have written is this:

```
        Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Material(
                  color: Color(0xFF3E4685),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  elevation: 6,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    height: 0,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_right_alt_sharp,
                      size: 50,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

And the output is this:
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6OLq.png)

I would like for it to be a bit more squished so less vertical height, I have tried using the height property but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SizedBox(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  child: Material(
   color: Color(0xFF3E4685),
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
   elevation: 6,
   child: MaterialButton(
    height: 0,
    onPressed: () {},
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
    child: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_right_alt_sharp,
      size: 50,
      color: Colors.white,
     ),
    ),
  ),
```

or you can use [ButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html)

```
ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: 200.0,
  height: 100.0,
  child: YourButton
),
```